Text Variable not updating in tkinter in replit
So i'm trying to make a program that required you to put in a bunch of data of employees, and the function im using to make these sets of data inputs doesnt return them changing.
Here's my code :
# Fonction pour créer les employés
def cree_employes(i, n):
   # Variables pour les options des employés
   typeEmploi = tk.StringVar(fenetre)
   lblTypeEmploi = tk.Label(cadreSecondaire)
   lblNombreHeures = tk.Label(cadreSecondaire)
   lblPourboire = tk.Label(cadreSecondaire)
   lblNomEmploye = tk.Label(cadreSecondaire)
   options = ["Secretaire", "Comptable", "Superviseur", "Concierge", "Marketeur"]
   optTypeEmploi = tk.OptionMenu(cadreSecondaire, typeEmploi, *options)
   nb_heures = tk.StringVar(fenetre)
   txtNombreHeures = tk.Entry(cadreSecondaire, width=3, textvariable=nb_heures)
   nb_pourboire = tk.StringVar(fenetre)
   txtPourboire = tk.Entry(cadreSecondaire, width=3, textvariable=nb_pourboire)
   nom_employe = tk.StringVar(fenetre)
   txtNomEmploye = tk.Entry(cadreSecondaire, width=11, textvariable=nom_employe)

   # Label pour le cadre des employés
   lblTitreSecondaire = tk.Label(cadreSecondaire)
   lblTitreSecondaire["text"] = "Employé " + str(n)
   lblTitreSecondaire.configure(font=("Arial", 12), bg="gray15", fg="white")
   lblTitreSecondaire.place(anchor=tk.CENTER, relx=.5, rely=.05+2.8*(i/10))

   # Configuration et placement des éléments d'entrée pour chaque employé
   txtNomEmploye.configure(font=("Arial", 11), bg="gray20", fg="white")
   txtNomEmploye.place(anchor=tk.CENTER, relx=.75, rely=.1+2.8*(i/10))

   lblNomEmploye["text"] = "Nom d'employé"
   lblNomEmploye.configure(font=("Arial", 11), bg="gray15", fg="white")
   lblNomEmploye.place(anchor=tk.CENTER, relx=.3, rely=.1+2.8*(i/10))

   typeEmploi.set("Secretaire")
   optTypeEmploi.configure(fg="white", bg="gray20")
   optTypeEmploi.place(anchor=tk.CENTER, relx=.75, rely=.15+2.8*(i/10))

   lblTypeEmploi["text"] = "Type d'emploi"
   lblTypeEmploi.configure(font=("Arial", 11), bg="gray15", fg="white")
   lblTypeEmploi.place(anchor=tk.CENTER, relx=.3, rely=.15+2.8*(i/10))

   txtNombreHeures.configure(font=("Arial", 11), bg="gray20", fg="white")
   txtNombreHeures.place(anchor=tk.CENTER, relx=.75, rely=.20+2.8*(i/10))

   lblNombreHeures["text"] = "Nombres d'heures"
   lblNombreHeures.configure(font=("Arial", 11), bg="gray15", fg="white")
   lblNombreHeures.place(anchor=tk.CENTER, relx=.3, rely=.20+2.8*(i/10))

   txtPourboire.configure(font=("Arial", 11), bg="gray20", fg="white")
   txtPourboire.place(anchor=tk.CENTER, relx=.75, rely=.25+2.8*(i/10))

   lblPourboire["text"] = "Pourboire"
   lblPourboire.configure(font=("Arial", 11), bg="gray15", fg="white")
   lblPourboire.place(anchor=tk.CENTER, relx=.3, rely=.25+2.8*(i/10))
   
   widgets = [lblTitreSecondaire, lblTypeEmploi, lblNombreHeures, lblTypeEmploi, lblPourboire, lblNomEmploye, txtNombreHeures, txtPourboire, txtNomEmploye, optTypeEmploi, txtNombreHeures]
   Liste = [nom_employe.get(), typeEmploi.get(), nb_heures.get(), nb_pourboire.get()]
   return Liste, widgets

So i've tried to print multiple texts to see where the problem lies, but it's just not working. I've tested entry widgets on different programs in replit and they work just fine. I've also asked this same question three hours ago with my full code but nobody answered so this is my second attempt.Sorry for the code being in french but it's pretty straightforward. Please help?

The answer hasn't changed since you previously asked the question: you're calling .get() on your StringVars immediately after creating them, there is no possibility that the user has entered anything into them yet.

I take it back. This solves my problem thanks so much !!

@jasonharper I can't believe I spent 3 hours looking at this code not realising this. For some reason i kept thinking that the function would be rerun when you press the button. Thanks!
